# Run my bash script on login and SEE terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, login

i need your help :)
I have some script that start on login (I set it on Application launcher preference) but i can't see terminal.
One script it's easy and make light on on my CMstorm keyboard and set numlock to ON.
Another script (too long) check update for every row with Internet, but i can't able to see if the process are in download mode or if script end.
I would like this script open terminal and run it into the terminal, in this case i will be able to see what script are doing.

My script is in $home/Desktop/Elaborati/script1.sh
I think it's necessary to create another script that lauch script1.sh in a new gnome-terminal...but I'm not able to do it. 
Can you help me please

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the startup entry to this:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c '~/Desktop/Elaborati/script1.sh'"
```

However, if you don't want the terminal to close once the script has finished executing, use this instead:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c '~/Desktop/Elaborati/script1.sh;echo Press any key to close this window...;read -sn1 null'"
```

Why 'bash -c'? To allow for variables to be parsed, and for multiple commands.

Comment: where I can write this command?in script launcher?

Comment: Where you would otherwise just put the path. (If you are using Ubuntu/Ubuntu  MATE,  you could add a new entry in the 'Startup Applications' setting.

Comment: yes i use just it, but i need to insert directly the command?or I must create a launcher.sh that call this command and/or more if i have?

Comment: Insert it directly.